# Unnesting json object

Tags: json

My sample json is

```
"multiList": [
{
"my_key" : "this is my key"
},
{
"my_text_box": "This is my text box"
},
```

]

How do I convert this to 
       {"my_key" : "this is my key"},
       {my_text_box": "This is my text box"},
   dynamically?

using jquery

Comment: This is not a valid JSON. Also please provide example code you're using this in. Do you actually mean to just get value for "multiList" key or do you actually mean to flatten the list in order to get something like `{"my_key": "this is my key", "my_text_box": "This is my text box"}`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense.  Are you asking to convert to two separate objects?  A string representation of those two objects? Something else?  I can do the first two:

```
var objOne = json.multiList[0];
var objTwo = json.multiList[1];

var objStr = JSON.stringify(json.multiList[0]) + ', '
    + JSON.stringify(json.multiList[1]);
```

If you want to add all of the separate properties into one object, you can just extend another object in a loop.

```
var obj = {};
json.multiList.forEach(function (elem) {
    for (k in elem) {
        if (elem.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            obj[k] = elem[k];
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/t2xyd/

This makes no consideration for the overriding of properties in `obj`.

Comment: I want to unnest the json object so it shows as [{"my_key": "this is my key", "my_text_box": "This is my text box"}] - basically 2 separate key value pairs